# Custom CSS and JS that would load only for a content type's view mode

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to load a custom css and js on my content type's view mode.
Can this be achieved in drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create a new library as follows:

[THEME].libraries.yml

```
mycontenttype:
  css:
    theme:
      path/to/my.file.css: {}
  js:
    path/to/my.file.js: {}
```

Next, you attach that library to the node in [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x):

```
function THEME_node_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\node\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  // Check the content type (bundle) and view mode:
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'mycontenttype' && $build['#view_mode'] == 'myviewmode') {
    // Attach your library in the form of MODULEKEY/LIBRARYKEY
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mycontenttype';
  }
}
```

Now your CSS and JS will be rendered on the page if/when a node of the given content type is rendered on the page with the given view mode.